# Autocomplete with React components

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, reactjs

I want a autosuggest workflow like below. Instead of displaying numeric ID, say 123 in a text field, I want to show custom information.

[image]

While I can do the rest with React, I still need to do autocomplete. I have two requirements:

1. When selected, provide a callback with rich data `{id: 123, title:"Prince Hall", info:"123 Foo St"}`
2. Have custom rendering that allows me to reuse JSX templates

JQueryUI and Twitter autocompletes have both features. But their item rendering takes is **string based**, but I want to reuse JSX templates which are virtual-dom based. I dont want to duplicate/hardcode JSX templates with string templates.

Comment: could you please add the code you've started with and what's not working? As written, this question is too broad, it's asking to select a component for you, and then write the code.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, yes I had a feeling that this question is a hard to answer, recommendation question. I started with JqueryUI's and Twitter autocomplete and they had custom rendering, but with string templates only; and using React's virtual dom with string rendering was an uncrackable problem. Thats why I asked if there is any autocomplete that can play well with React rendering. Sorry the wording was too lazy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select). It is simple, beautiful and currently has the most Github stars. [Live demo here](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/).

Answer (score 5):

React-Autosuggest is a component that meets the requirements. It has custom rendering that works natively with React elements.

We can make it handle JS objects instead of plain strings.

1. the `onSuggestionSelected` props is a callback to get the selected suggestion
2. `suggestionRenderer` method takes suggestion and returns React markup

http://react-autosuggest.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Another powerful Auto-Complete/Auto-Suggest module is '[downshift](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift)' which has a wide variety of props for better customization. Different from react-select which opens as a select-box, downshift is a textbox which unhides a suggestion list of words as its value changes.